# Como bloquear una app android para que no pueda cerrarse

Tags: android

Antes que nada gracias por su ayuda, el problema que tengo es el siguiente:
En mi trabajo manejamos tablets para hacer cobros desde ellas mediante una aplicación propia, el problema esta en que los usuarios utilizan la tablet para youtube, face, etc., ya he intentado usar la cuenta de family link pero les da por quitarla.
Como podria hacer una app que no se pueda cerrar, que no permita que se usen mas app como en el banco o como en algunas compañías que usan una app y no puede cerrarse.

Comment: Yo probaría creando un app de launcher que solo muestre la aplicación de cobros. Así los usuarios no podrían instalar otras apps ni abrirlas ya que no se mostrarían los iconos.

Comment: Perfecto, voy a intentarlo gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Android tiene una function 'App Pinning' ('Fijar Aplicaciones'), que te podria ayudar. Mira [esta pagina del Centro de Asistencia](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9455138?hl=es).

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, recuerda revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Gracias @Glorfindel, ya lo intente pero al reiniciar se pierde la configuración y se debe volver a fijar la app. Esto no me es muy util porque seguido dejan sin carga las tablets en los puntos de cobro.